# Updating a hibernate entity with CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm currently writing my first spring boot Kotlin application and am trying to create a rest API with JPA persistence. The basics are going fine but I'm struggling with updating a model on a patch endpoint (@patchMapping).

I want to adhere to proper rest standards and for that reason I'm hitting the patch endpoint with `@PatchMapping("/company/{id}")`.

I would like to be able to call the CrudRepository in a way like this.

```
  @PatchMapping("/company/{id}")
  fun update(@PathVariable id: Long, @RequestBody updateRequest: Company) : Company {
    return repository.update(updateRequest, id)
  }
```

but it appears as if the spring way to do it is to pass the id of the object you're going to update within the requestBody? e.g.

```
repository.save(updateRequest)
```

which then auto merges the object. But this conflicts with any sane rest convention...

is there an integrated solution available for what I want to achieve? I'd like to refrain from writing my own logic as I'd hoped spring to have this functionality.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom method with ```@Query``` to update the particular field ?. It is very rare you update the primary key of the entity and it is mostly unlikely to happen. I can understand if you want to update the other properties of the entity not the primary key itself.

Comment: I'm not trying to modify the primary key here, what I want is to access the patch endpoint by supplying the primary key as url parameter then finding the corresponding model, updating attributes en saving it.

Comment: Great. in that case you can get the entity using ```findById(id)``` and then update the properties and use ```save()``` it calls merge instead of persist because its an existing entity. if you dont like doing this way, use custom method with ```@Query``` native query option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
 @RestController
 class Controller(private val service: CompanyService) {
   @PatchMapping("/company/{id}")
   fun update(@PathVariable id: Long, @RequestBody company: Company): Company {
     return service.updateCompany(company, id)
   }
 }

 @Service
 class CompanyService (private val repository: CompanyRepository) {
   @Transactional
   fun updateCompany(company: Company, id: Long): Company {
     val companyToUpdate = repository.findOne(id)
     companyToUpdate.setSomething(company.getSomething)
     raturn companyToUpdate;
   }
 }

 interface CompanyRepository : CrudRepository<Company, Long>
```

Comment: This would be an option, yes, it's a shame though I have to wrap the CrudRepository to add this functionality. How would I go about to make this service class example injectable? I've tried the structure but I'm getting the error

 `No qualifying bean of type CompanyService`

Comment: I forgot annotations like  @Service.
Examples you can find [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/)